# Matrix in $M_2(\mathbf{R})$ of order $2$ has trace $0$

Tags: matrices, trace, gre-exam

I found this question in a GRE math subject test from 1987. It's problem 61 at [http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/GRE_8767_test.pdf](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_gre_w2015/GRE_8767_test.pdf). It boils down to the following.

Prove that if $A$ is a $2$x$2$ matrix with real entries not equal to $I$ or $-I$ such that $A=A^{-1},$ then $\textrm{tr}(A)=0.$

A nice proof might use the identity $\textrm{tr}(BC)=\textrm{tr}(CB).$ I know how to prove the result from looking at the matrix components, so I'd prefer to see a "coordinate-free" proof if possible.

Comment: The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. $A = A^{-1}$ implies $A^2=I$ or $(A-I)(A+I)=0$ so the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @amsmath Thankyou!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given that $\,A=A^{-1}\,$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix
and $\,A\notin \{I,-I\}.$

Now $\,A\,$ satisfies
the equation $$A^2-\textrm{tr}(A)A+\det(A)I=0 \tag{1}$$
by the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem),  but
$$A^2-I=AA^{-1}-I=I-I=0. \tag{2}$$
By property of determinants this implies that
$$\det(A)^2 = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad \det(A)=\pm1. \tag{3}$$
Together $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply
$$\textrm{tr}(A)A-(1+\det(A))I=0 \tag{4}$$
If $\,\textrm{tr}(A)=0\,$ then $\,\det(A)=-1\,$ and we are done.

If $\,\textrm{tr}(A)\ne0,\,$ then equation $(4)$ implies that
$$A = \frac{1+\det(A)}{\textrm{tr}(A)}I. \tag{5}$$
From equation $(3)$, if $\,\det(A)=-1,\,$ then $\,A=0I\,$ which
is not invertible, and thus
$$\det(A)=1,\quad A=\frac2{\textrm{tr}(A)}I,\quad\text{ and }
\quad  \textrm{tr}(A)=\pm2.\tag{6}$$ However, this implies
that $\,A=\pm I\,$ which contradicts the
assumption $\,A\notin \{I,-I\}.$